# "Todos.user" must be a "UserProfile" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Getting Error "Todos.user" must be a "UserProfile" instance. can someone explain why?
I want users in Todos should point to UserProfile and whatever I save in Todos should be displayed in /profile/  ?

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birth =models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name



class Todos(models.Model):
    user     = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created  = models.DateField()
    start_time     = models.TimeField()
    end_time     = models.TimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.user)
```

Form

```
class todosform(ModelForm):
    title       = forms.CharField(label=(u'Todo'))
    created     = forms.DateField(label=(u'Date'))
    start_time        = forms.TimeField(label=(u'Start Time'))
    end_time        = forms.TimeField(label=(u'End Time'))
    #user        = forms.CharField(label=(u'username')
    class Meta:
        model = Todos
        exclude=('user',)


#url todo url(r'^todo/$', 'registration.views.todo'), 

def todo(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated(): 
        Todos.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =formtodos(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():# All validation rules pass
           todoss = form.save(commit=False)
           todoss.user = request.user
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        form = formtodos() 

    context = {'form':form}
    return render_to_response('todo.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))



#url profile url(r'^profile/$', 'registration.views.Profile'),

@login_required # decorator to check if request login
def Profile(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated(): #if user not logged in
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/') 
    #model = request.user.todos_set.all().order_by('created')[:7]
    #u = Todos.objects.filter(created_by = request.user).get(pk=user)
    registration = request.user.get_profile
    context = {'registration':registration }
    return render_to_response('profile.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `user` field on `Todos` is a ForeignKey to `UserProfile`, not `User`. `request.user` is an instance of `User`. You could to this:

```
todoss.user = request.user.get_profile()
```

Comment: Keep in mind what get_profile() will be deprecated in Django 1.5

Comment: Exception Value:  
UserProfile matching query does not exist ... however there is already a UserProfile